# Two Simple HTML/CSS Questions

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have this site: http://example.com/

And I was wondering two things - A) how can I prevent the side bar from overlapping the text of the resume when the window is small and I scroll? I want the sidebar to scroll vertically, but not horizontally.

B) How can I add little buttons into different parts of the margin? I want to add little buttons to go to my blog, Twitter and such.

Comment: I don't seem to see the side bar overlapping the content in the browsers I have looked at this with. What browser and version are you seeing this? It may be helpful to post a screenshot of the problem you are seeing.

Comment: This question needs to be closed as it does not supply a [mcve] here, within the question and 8 years later the problem pointed to in the link probably no longer exists.

Comment: @Rob As the person who posted the question, no, the problem no longer exists, and at this point I am more likely to answer a question like this, rather than ask it. Agreed on closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need javascript to do this properly.

try sticking this in your head section and change your css #sidebar to position:absolute;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onscroll = moveEle;
  function moveEle() {

    //Alter top to be how many pixels you want from the top of the window
    var top = 50;

    ele = document.getElementById('sidebar');

    if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {
      ele.style.top = (document.body.scrollTop + top) + "px";
    } else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
     ele.style.top = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + top) + "px";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Oh, and the buttons, you could just put some anchor tags in the sidebar as well with href pointing to whatever addresses you have at twitter etc. Style them with display:block and then style further. You can make them the size you want with whatever background color and border or background image.

Comment: Also, it overlaps the graphic I have put at the top of the resume.

Comment: There are two things you can do to prevent the overlap:

Comment: There are two things you can do to prevent the overlap: 1. set 'var top = 50' to be bigger so the whole menu sits lower, or 2. you can add 'if(document.body.scrollTop > whatever-height-value-from-top-you-want-the-menu-to-stop-moving)' into the function) and likewise for the document.documentElement.scrollTop version. As for the choppy bit, damn, not sure why that is, works fine on my computer, but then I do have a very good spec :)

Answer (score 1):

My method for the Buttons, would be not to create individual classes, but create a `<div>`.

```
#navigation{margin-top:-50px}
```

Now, all buttons and all things in that navigation will be -50px to the top.
But, it get's better!

```
#navigation .littledifference{margin-top:-35px !important}
```

Now, you can set the button (or again, anything) in that navigation to have this class, and the margin will be different!  This saves on having extra coding for every single button.

**Edit** as Psyrus says above, you could also use `<a>` tags.  This requires a fair amount of work from my own personal experience, though you can do anything with them.  My system above should still work though - just make sure the `<a>` tags still are inside the `#navigation` and don't have conflicting `margin` attributes.  The class selector should still work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use % value.

```
#wrap{width:100%; max-width:1024px;}
#sidebar{width:15%;}
#main{width:80%; padding:10px 2.5%;}
```

This way, when you will resize your window, your content size will adjust in consequence. So they won't overlap.

Comment: The problem is only that the sidebar is fixed, which I do want vertically (I want it to be there on the side wherever they are on the y-axis), however when the window is smaller and I scroll across the x-axis I do not want it to cover the body.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the position:fixed by a relative on the sidebar and than add a little jquery script that verify the scrollTop position and reajust the top position of your sidebar. This way it will look like fixed vertically, but will never overlap the main ?

Comment: Possibly? My Javascript is still in its learning phase. I initially figured I'd need Javascript but everyone told me that position: fixed; would do what I needed it to do, which clearly seems not to be the case

Comment: Hrm, tried that and it didn't seem to work, mind looking and seeing what I did wrong?

Comment: $(function() {
 $(document).scroll(function() {
  $('#sidebar').css({top: $(document).scrollTop()+'px'});
 });
}); and make sure your #sidebar have position:relative, not fixed

Answer (score 0):

To prevent overlapping You can use negative value and positive Values for specific padding and margin so that you can place any `<div>` at any place you want.One thing you have to keep in mind you can give negative values and negative percentage while setting padding and margin

```
    .ClassName
    {
    padding-left:-20px;
    padding-top:-10%;
    }
```